# read access violation while reading file with ifstream

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to save a vector to a file and read it back. I manage to save it , but when I try to load it I get 1 element then an error.
If I skip an element by loading it in buffer (commented code) I manage to load next correctly. When the body of the loop end I get the error. I try to make the loop independent of the steram but I still got the error.
My load method is

```
void Load() {
        //cars is private vector
        cars.empty();
        lastIndex = 0;    
        ifstream f(path.c_str());
        if (f.fail())
            return;
        //while (f.peek() != EOF) {
        while (true) {
            //char* buffer = new char[sizeof(CarInfo)];
            //f.read(buffer, sizeof(CarInfo));
            CarInfo car = CarInfo(&f);
            if (car.ID() > lastIndex)
                lastIndex = car.ID();
            //Add is public method to add items in cars
            Add(car);

        }
        f.close();
    }
```

my save method

```
    void Save() {
        ofstream f(path.c_str());
        for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
            cars[i].Write(&f);
        }
    }
```

my class

```
class CarInfo
{
public :
    int ID() { return id; }
    string Color() { return color; }
    string Brand() { return brand; }
    double Price() { return price; }
    void Discount() { price = price - price * .1; }
    void Read(ifstream* in) { in->read((char*)this, sizeof(CarInfo)); }
    void Write(ofstream* out) { out->write((char*)this, sizeof(CarInfo)); }
    CarInfo(int ID,string Color,string Brand,double Price) {
        if (Color.find_first_not_of(' ') == std::string::npos)
            throw invalid_argument("Invalid Color!");
        if (Color.length() > 20)
            throw invalid_argument("Color too long!");
        if (Brand.find_first_not_of(' ') == std::string::npos)
            throw invalid_argument("Invalid Brand!");
        if (Brand.length() > 20)
            throw invalid_argument("Brand too long!");
        if (Price < 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid Price!");

        id = ID;
        color = Color;
        brand = Brand;
        price = Price;
    }
    CarInfo(ifstream* in) { Read(in); }
    CarInfo() { id = -1; color = "not set"; brand = "not set";price = 0;}
private:
    int id;
    string color;
    string brand;
    double price;
};
```

the error is

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
>   _Pnext was 0x6BD974.

in "xrmemory" on line 1293. If there is better way to do this,  im open to suggestions. The task only says to save it as single binary file

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger to solve such issues on your own.

Comment: `cars.empty();` - your probably want `cars.clear();`.

Comment: im using the debuger but skips from my code directly to some c++ lib with the error, and i dont have problem with pushing the elements to the vector nor cleaning it

Comment: That `while(true)` loop never ends.

Comment: it was a test ... it dosnt matter if the loop never ends cuz i get the erro on the end of the first iteration anyway

Comment: I find that the problem is cuz `void Read(ifstream* in) { in->read((char*)this, sizeof(CarInfo)); }` but i have no idea why or how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work, but I still wanna know why the first doesn't work. Here is my solution...

```
while (f.peek() != EOF) {
            char* buffer = new char[sizeof(CarInfo)];
            f.read(buffer, sizeof(CarInfo));
            CarInfo *car = (CarInfo*)(buffer);
            Add(CarInfo(car->ID(),car->Color(),car->Brand(),car->Price()));
        }
```